# Unable to add Google Account (Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome)

Tags: gnome, online-accounts

I have been trying to add my Google account under Online Account section, but, for some reason, the authentication windows go blank during the final step after I enter email address and password.

Here is the screenshot ->
[image: Screenshot]

I was able to add the same account through my laptop; this issue exists only on my PC.

I tried restarting the PC, switching to a different Internet connection, upgrading available packages, checked logs for any clues but could not find anything.

I hope that someone here will point me in the right direction.

**Update:**
I am using Google Suite if this is relevant to the issue.

I downloaded the fresh copy of iso and did new install twice but I keep having the same issue. (07/05/2017)

Comment: This happens often. Usually it is enough to press F5 at that point, or to go back and try again.

Comment: @Jos I have been trying for the past 3 days. Pressing F5 does nothing but I have tried Right Click and Reload.

Comment: @jos, google has a new method for apps to communicate and you have to set up your phone to get it to work. Let OP see the dup I added

Comment: @George I am facing a completely different issue. I cannot add Google account to online account.

Comment: Its the same please see the end of  my post and from your image. I had this issue and I solved it by using my phone

Comment: Follow the link in the post and after setting up your phone you will able to use it to get past that sign in stage...

Comment: @George I am using Google Suite. When I go to the link you have mentioned it throws an error `Your phone can’t be used to sign in to this Google Account`

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: @George OnePlus 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58186/discussion-between-george-and-kevin-s).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an ongoing bug for 16.04 Gnome, [see here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkit2gtk/+bug/1687019)

Please visit the bug linked, indicate that it affects you too, and subscribe so that you can be notified when the bug is squashed.